# Extracting JSON data locally using .getJSON but data will not appear

Tags: javascript, json

First off, I am trying to parse JSON and I'm using a file locally.

When I run the following:

```
$.getJSON('/trivia_demos.json', function(data) {
   alert("It worked!); });
```

The alert box comes up and I can confirm I am calling the right file locally. Console.log works as well. So far, so good.

I now want to pull several parts of the data and show them on the page. The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lovxtrfh/) is here, but the relevant code is the following:

```
    $.getJSON('/trivia_demos.json', function(data) {
    var items = [] 
     $.each(data.reponse, function(item, i) {
        items.push('<li id="' + i.order + '">' + i.question + ' - ' + i.answer + '</li>');
        });

$('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
 }).appendTo('#example');});
```

In effect, I want the order, question, and answer appended to my div "#example". When I load the page, nothing happens though. In light of my first point, I believe I am screwing up the construction of the JQuery to target those three pieces of data and display them.

I believe something is missing between calling the json file and actually accessing the json object.

Also, in the trivia_demos.json file, the following json is present.

```
[{"id":1,"order":1,"question":"Who was the only American President to 
learn English as a second language? ","answer1":"John Quincy Adams",
"answer2":"Martin van Buren","answer3":"William McKinley ",
"answer4":"Andrew Jackson","correcta":"Martin van Buren",
"published":"2014-11-04","url":"http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"}]
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle example is not working because you have not included jQuery on the page. If you open up your browser's developer tools, you will see an error message that states "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Use the dropdown menus on the lefthand side of the page to include the appropriate libraries (e.g. jQuery).

Comment: `$.getJSON` is **async**. This means that when you append the items to the `ul` element, the async operation may not have finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [jquery.getjson documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) it $each loop should work with just data parameter:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Also, I tested your code without json part and it worked fine apart from `i.answer` that I changed to `i.answer1` also `data.response` was changed to `data`:

```
$.each(data, function (item, i) {
    items.push('<li id="' + i.order + '">' + i.question + ' - ' + i.answer1 +  '</li>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/v19r9001/)

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. The question and answer are now being parsed successfully and displayed in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var json = '[{"id":1,"order":1,"question":"Who was the only American President to  learn English as a second language? ","answer1":"John Quincy Adams","answer2":"Martin van Buren","answer3":"William McKinley ","answer4":"Andrew Jackson","correcta":"Martin van Buren","published":"2014-11-04","url":"http://example.com/trivia_demos/1.json"}]';

        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        var content = '<ul>';
        $(obj).each(function()
        {
            var li = '<li id="'+ this.order +'">' + this.question + ' - ' + i.answer + '</li>';
            content += li;                
        });
        content += '</ul>';
        $('#example').html(content);
```